# What type of View is better in this situation? (screenshot attached)

Tags: android

I'm creating UI for app and i don't know what is the more efficient way to create this type of buttons in Android. It has behavior like checkboxes (has checked\unchecked state) but must look like regular buttons. I want create something like on screenshot:

[image]

Can i customize checkboxes to get this result or should I use textviews or maybe other type of views? I need to handle this buttons states, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: You could use a [compound button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
</shape>
```

and set as background